# Select a row based on two other columns R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe `df`

```
df = data.frame(L = rep(letters[1:6], each = 2), 
                M = rep(letters[7:12]), 
                freq = sample(c(5, 10), replace = FALSE))

   L M freq
1  a g    5
2  a h   10
3  b i    5
4  b j   10
5  c k    5
6  c l   10
7  d g    5
8  d h   10
9  e i    5
10 e j   10
11 f k    5
12 f l   10
```

I want to select the most frequent M for each L.

In this example the output would show:

```
h, j, l, h, j, l
```

Frequency is not necessarily every second value in the actual problem.

How can I do this easily?

I've tried a `tapply` approach, but get stuck here because this seems to only apply to variables and can't be used to subset a subset data frame. (This didn't result in anything close so I won't post the approach)

Comment: A base R option in addition to those from the linked question would be `with(df[order(-df$freq),], M[!duplicated(L)])`

Comment: @docendodiscimus maybe add/update answer in the target post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution using `dplyr`

```
df %>% group_by(L) %>% top_n(1, freq) %>% .$M
#### [1] h j l h j l
```

eventually transform into character at the end...

Comment: As of `dplyr` v0.7, you can use the more idiomatic `... %>% pull(M)` instead of `... %>% .$M`

Answer (score 2):

We can do

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(M = M[which.max(freq)]), L]
#   L M
#1: a h
#2: b j
#3: c l
#4: d h
#5: e j
#6: f l
```

---

Or `order` the 'freq' and select the first 'M' for each 'L'

```
setDT(df)[order(-freq), .(M = M[1]) , L]
```